# Queue problems across multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, queue

There are many questions and articles on the subject of using a .NET `Queue` properly within a multi threaded application, however I can't find subject on our specific problem.

We have a Windows Service that receives messages onto a queue via one thread and is then dequeued and processed within another.

We're using `lock` when queuing and dequeuing, and the service had run fine for around 2 years without any problems. One day we noticed that thousands of messages had been logged (and so had been queued) but were never dequeued/processed, they seem to have been skipped somehow, which shouldn't be possible for a queue.

We can't replicate the circumstances that caused it as we have no real idea what caused it considering that day was no different from any of the others as far as we're aware.

The only idea we have is to do with the concurrency of the queue. We're not using the `ConcurrentQueue` data-type, which we plan on using in the hope it is a remedy.

One idea, looking at the source of the Queue type, is that it uses arrays internally, which have to be resized once these buffers have reached a certain length. We hypothesised that when this is being done some of the messages were lost.

Another idea from our development manager is that using multiple threads on a multicore processor setup means that even though locks are used, the individual cores are working on the data in their local registers, which can cause them to be working on different data. He said they don't work on the same memory and seems to think `lock` only works as expected one a single core processor using multiple threads.

Reading more about ConcurrentQueue's use of `volatile` I'm not sure that this would help, as I've read that using lock provides a stronger guarantee of threads using the most up-to-date state of memory.

I don't have much knowledge on this specific subject, so my question is whether the manager's idea sounds plausible, and whether we might have missed something that's required for the queue to be used properly.

Code snippet for reference (forgive the messy code, it does need refactoring):

```
public sealed class Message
{

    public void QueueMessage(long messageId, Message msg)
    {
        lock (_queueLock)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(new QueuedMessage() { Id = messageId, Message = msg });
        }
    }

    public static void QueueMessage(string queueProcessorName, long messageId, Message msg)
    {
        lock (_messageProcessors[queueProcessorName]._queueLock)
        {
            _messageProcessors[queueProcessorName].QueueMessage(messageId, msg);
            _messageProcessors[queueProcessorName].WakeUp(); // Ensure the thread is awake
        }
    }

    public void WakeUp()
    {
        lock(_monitor)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(_monitor);
        }
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        while (!_stop)
        {
            QueuedMessage currentMessage = null;

            try
            {
                lock (_queueLock)
                {
                    currentMessage = _queue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
            catch(InvalidOperationException i)
            {
                // Nothing in the queue
            }

            while(currentMessage != null)
            {
                IContext context = new Context();
                DAL.Message msg = null;

                try
                {
                    msg = context.Messages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentMessage.Id);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle these exceptions better. Possible infinite loop.

                    continue; // Keep retrying until it works
                }

                if (msg == null) { 
                    // TODO: Log missing message
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    msg.Status = DAL.Message.ProcessingState.Processing;
                    context.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle these exceptions better. Possible infinite loop.

                    continue; // Keep retrying until it works
                }

                bool result = false;
                try {
                    Transformation.TransformManager mgr = Transformation.TransformManager.Instance();
                    Transformation.ITransform transform = mgr.GetTransform(currentMessage.Message.Type.Name, currentMessage.Message.Get("EVN:EventReasonCode"));

                    if (transform != null){
                        msg.BeginProcessing = DateTime.Now;
                        result = transform.Transform(currentMessage.Message);

                        msg.EndProcessing = DateTime.Now;
                        msg.Status = DAL.Message.ProcessingState.Complete;
                    }
                    else {
                        msg.Status = DAL.Message.ProcessingState.Failed;
                    }

                    context.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        context = new Context();
                        // TODO: Handle these exceptions better
                        Error err = context.Errors.Add(context.Errors.Create());

                        err.MessageId = currentMessage.Id;
                        if (currentMessage.Message != null)
                        {
                            err.EventReasonCode = currentMessage.Message.Get("EVN:EventReasonCode");
                            err.MessageType = currentMessage.Message.Type.Name;
                        }
                        else {
                            err.EventReasonCode = "Unknown";
                            err.MessageType = "Unknown";
                        }

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Exception occured\n");
                        int level = 0;
                        while (e != null && level < 10)
                        {
                            sb.Append("Message: ");
                            sb.Append(e.Message);
                            sb.Append("\nStack Trace: ");
                            sb.Append(e.StackTrace);
                            sb.Append("\n");

                            e = e.InnerException;
                            level++;
                        }

                        err.Text = sb.ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ne) { 

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Exception occured\n");
                        int level = 0;
                        while (ne != null && level < 10)
                        {
                            sb.Append("Message: ");
                            sb.Append(ne.Message);
                            sb.Append("\nStack Trace: ");
                            sb.Append(ne.StackTrace);
                            sb.Append("\n");

                            ne = ne.InnerException;
                            level++;
                        }

                        EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", sb.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    context.Commit();

                    lock (_queueLock)
                    {
                        currentMessage = _queue.Dequeue();
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                { 
                    currentMessage = null;    // No more messages in the queue 
                }
                catch (Exception ne)
                {

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Exception occured\n");
                    int level = 0;
                    while (ne != null && level < 10)
                    {
                        sb.Append("Message: ");
                        sb.Append(ne.Message);
                        sb.Append("\nStack Trace: ");
                        sb.Append(ne.StackTrace);
                        sb.Append("\n");

                        ne = ne.InnerException;
                        level++;
                    }

                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", sb.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
                }
            }

            lock (_monitor)
            {
                if (_stop) break;

                Monitor.Wait(_monitor, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_pollingInterval));

                if (_stop) break;
            }
        }
    }

    private object _monitor = new object();
    private int _pollingInterval = 10;
    private volatile bool _stop = false;
    private object _queueLock = new object();
    private Queue<QueuedMessage> _queue = new Queue<QueuedMessage>();
    private static IDictionary<string, Message> _messageProcessors = new Dictionary<string, Message>();
}
```

Comment: It's very difficult to answer without code. What I can tell you based on my experience: queues do not suffer from being shared on multiple cores as long as they are protected by locks. Locks indeed create memory barrier which guarantee that your threads won't work on different data (otherwise, it would be practically impossible to share even a boolean between threads as they are very likely to be cached due to their small size). SO my first and last guess would be: your problem in in the code around the queue, not the queue itself (failed to insert? dequeue but dropped?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Bruno. This supports my idea that volatile wouldn't be the solution. I've added code for reference.

Comment: Lock works depending on what are used as the object to lock.

Comment: @KingoftheNorth Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: [TPL DataFlow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html) is perfect for these kinds of "queues with parallelism" scenarios, and allows you to take your mind away from all the messy synchronization problems and concentrate on your data processing. It might take a few hours of tinkering to grok what it brings to the table, but, from your description, this is the droid your looking for.

Comment: As you already mentioned, use ConcurrentQueue (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @RichardSchneider we will use ConcurrentQueue, it just doesn't sit right that if `lock` is used properly (I think we are) then `violatile` shouldn't provide any additional benefit.

Comment: Also consider `BlockingCollection` (which uses `ConcurrentQueue` behind the scenes).

Comment: looking at your code, I would make two suggestions. First is use the same object for the lock of the queue and the pulse. Second would be to replace your try/catch block with if (queue.Count > 0) dequeue(); It's much cleaner :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Bruno. Is there something potentially dangerous about using a different lock object for the pulse and queue?

Comment: `lock`, `Pulse`, `Monitor`, `Thread`... these are all abstracted away by higher level libraries, and as stated above, you should really look into them. Why muddy your code and battle these subtle threading issues when they've already been solved?

Comment: using more than 1 lock may result in deadlocks if used the wrong way. I don't see any in your code but usually I try to minimize the number of different locks to 1 in the same code.

Answer (score 1):

> so my question is whether the manager's idea sounds plausible

Uhm. No. If all those synchronization measures would only work on single core machines, the world would have ended in complete Chaos decades ago.

> and whether we might have missed something that's required for the queue to be used properly.

As far as your description goes, you should be fine. I would look at how you *found out* that you have that problem. logs coming in but then vanishing without being properly dequeued, wouldn't that be the default case if I simply turned off the service or rebooted the machine? Are you sure you lost them while your application was actually *running*?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can say that we definitely know the messages were lost while the service was running as we had to restart it to fix it temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the object to be used for the lock as private object.

If you try this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test1 = new Test();
            Task Scan1 = Task.Run(() => test1.Run("1"));


            Test test2 = new Test();
            Task Scan2 = Task.Run(() => test2.Run("2"));

            while(!Scan1.IsCompleted || !Scan2.IsCompleted)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private object _queueLock = new object();
        public async Task Run(string val)
        {
            lock (_queueLock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{val} locked");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine($"{val} unlocked");
            }
        }
    }
```

You will notice that the code that lies under the lock is executed even if another thread is running inside.

But if you change

```
private object _queueLock = new object();
```

To

```
private static object _queueLock = new object();
```

It changes how your lock works.

Now, this being your issue depends on if you have multiple instances that class or everything is running withing that same class.

Comment: Good point. I did think of this but, at the moment at least, there's only ever one instance of the class in question and its all self-contained.